# No known class method for selector in Parse installed files

Tags: swift, xcode, parse-platform, cocoapods

I just created a fresh xcode project and installed cocoapods of parse 
including FacebookUtils , TwitterUtils and PodsUI
after installing and running the new.xcworkspace file i get these 2 errors

No known class method for selector 'extractPermissionsFromResponse:grantedPermissions:declinedPermissions:'

No known class method for selector 'objectForJSONString:error:'

```swift
[FBSDKInternalUtility extractPermissionsFromResponse:result
                                      grantedPermissions:grantedPermissions
                                     declinedPermissions:declinedPermissions];
```

```swift
NSDictionary *state = [FBSDKInternalUtility objectForJSONString:parameters[@"state"] error:&error];
  _parameters.challenge = [FBSDKUtility URLDecode:state[@"challenge"]];
```